# Two quadratic polynomial fraction sums up to be 8

Tags: polynomials, fractions

Find all real solutions for:
$$\frac{3x}{2x^2-7x+7} + \frac{27x}{2x^2+6x+7} = 8$$

My work is down in the Answers section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\text{Let }A=2x^2+6x+7$$
$$\frac{3x}{A-13x} + \frac{27x}A = 8$$

$$3Ax + 27x(A-13x) = 8A(A-13x)$$
$$3Ax + 27Ax-351x = 8A^2-104Ax$$
$$8A^2-134Ax+351x = 0$$
$$(4A-13x)(2A-27x)=0$$

---

$$4A-13x=0$$
$$8x^2+24x+28-13x = 0$$
$$8x^2+11x+28=0$$
$$\Delta<0\implies\text{No real solutions}$$

---

$$2A-27x=0$$
$$4x^2+12x+14-27x=0$$
$$4x^2-15x+14=0\implies x=2, \frac74$$

Comment: note: you can also use the midpoint $\frac{-7+6}2=-\frac 12$ and $A=4x^2-x+14$ for a tiny bit of easier calculations but it leads to exactly the same two quadratics at the end, quite a nice idea you had there.